# .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 doesn't work on localhost

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to implement a 404 error page. I have this project structure:

```
+Project
+---index.html
+---404.html
+---.htaccess
```

My .htaccess contains this line: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`

but this URL doesn't show my 404.html page:

`http://localhost:63342/Project/wrong.html`

Instead, I get the default Opera 404 page: https://ibb.co/XsFq5nZ

Whereas, my 404.html page looks like this: https://ibb.co/ZX7XB1d

The response from wrong.html is this: https://ibb.co/mJ2KztK

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
>
> http://localhost:63342/Project/wrong.html
> ```

It would seem you have not specified a root-relative URL-path. From your URL structure, it should be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Project/404.html
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Try resetting to the default Apache error document:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

Test that and then add your custom error document:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 404 /Project/404.html
```

Make sure your `404.html` file contains enough content. Some browsers will default an error response if the response received from the server is too small.

Comment: @AleksandrNovik What is the exact response you get (edit your question to add this information). Including the HTTP response code. Are these all the directives you have in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: edited. And yes, those are only files I have in my Project folder.

Comment: What about other directives in the `.htaccess` file, or is the `ErrorDocument` the only directive? Any other `.htaccess` files (perhaps in the root)?

Comment: there's nothing else in `.htaccess`. And I did what You added to your answer. Doesn't seem to help either...

Comment: @AleksandrNovik Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled on your server? If you type any _nonsense_ in your `.htaccess` file do you get an error? (This should trigger a 500 Internal Server Error.)